# WPF Datagrid unable to sort integer column

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, datagrid

I have a WPF Datagrid which I have set the item source using LinqToSQL. It is working fine except for one issue. I can't click the column header to sort those columns that are typed as INT in the database. Actually I can click the header to sort the primary key ID which is typed as INT, but the other INT type columns are un-clickable. Any idea what's going on here and how to fix it?

Edit:

The solution turned out to be simple. The columns in questions were set as nullable in the dbml designer. Simply changing this property to false corrected the sorting issue.

Comment: Can you please share some xaml of the DataGrid instance and your ViewModel code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple. The columns in questions were set as nullable in the dbml designer. Simply changing this property to false corrected the sorting issue.